# Hide console logs in JEST test

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, jestjs

I'm new to JEST and testing in general and having trouble figuring out the following.
I have the following script that is part of a CLI tool.

I would like to stop the spinner outputs when testing.

I have tried spyOn/mock, but to no avail.

```
const ora = require('ora');
const spinner = new ora();
const chalk = require('chalk');
const fs = require('fs');

module.exports = path =>
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    spinner.text = chalk.blue('Creating directory...');
    spinner.start();
    fs.mkdir(path, err => {
      if (!err) {
        spinner.succeed(chalk.bgGreen('Directory created\n'));
        resolve(true);
      } else {
        spinner.fail(chalk.bgRed(`Directory already exists: ${path}`));
        reject(err);
      }
    });
  });
```

this is my test:

```
const createDir = require('./utils/createDir');
const fs = require('fs');

describe('createDir function', () => {
  const folders = {
    base: './.test',
    fail: './.test/fail',
    success: './.test/success'
  };

  beforeAll(() => {
    fs.mkdirSync(folders.fail, { recursive: true });
  });

  afterAll(() => {
    fs.rmdirSync(folders.base, { recursive: true });
  });

  it('creates the directory', async () => {
    await expect(createDir(folders.success)).resolves.toBe(true);
  });

  it('fails if directory exists', async () => {
    await expect(createDir(folders.fail)).rejects.toThrow();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to just add

```
jest.mock('ora')
```

in the beginning of your test. It will auto-mock the entire library replacing each of the methods with `jest.fn()` (without any implementation) so the calls from the implementation will have no effect on the output.

EDIT by Ben:

The functional mock turned out to be this:

```js
jest.mock('ora', () => {
  return jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
    return {
      start: () => {},
      fail: () => {},
      succeed: () => {}
    };
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, about to mark for correct reply, tho it did not seem to automock its methods. Could it be due to using an instance of ora in my code?

You pointed me to the right direction regardless, and I mocked out the methods I am using.

Comment: @BenS I was curious to check why it's not working and it's because the library is actually exporting a [factory function](https://github.com/sindresorhus/ora/blob/df549b4e4541c675bb53f06582e0cc2827b62d71/index.js#L327) instead of a class